# Show current ping to website on Taksbar

Tags: taskbar, ping, monitoring, notification-area, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor my current internet connection quality by showing the ping-response to a website like google in the taskbar on the right side. I'm using Windows 8.1.
Kind of like [netspeedmonitor](http://www.floriangilles.de/software/netspeedmonitor/), but for the ping. Any suggestions?

I want to stop using the command line to ping Google.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? [ALSEDI Pinger](http://alsedi.com/pinger.php).

Not exactly "in the taskbar" but it keeps a record of the ping-history. Or else you wouldn't know you had problems a few minutes ago.

[image: Pinger]
[image: Pinger]

Comment: Kind of, but this tool shows all pings with a response <1s as good. I need to know how fast the response was.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite an old question. I'm currently using perfgraph - http://www.codefromthe70s.org/perfgraph3.aspx

It's free and it has more features than what you're looking for, the graph would look like this:

[taskbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vK9q.png)
hope this helps!

Comment: looking good, thanks! this isn't open source by any chance, right?

Comment: i do not think this is open-source. even if it were, it would be using an old code-base. the good thing about this is it works even with the latest windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Right. I'm just wondering since I really want to build a modern version but the whole integrating-into-Taskbar thing is really a pain.