# How can I see my ping on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, internet, ping

For the purpose of playing online games, I'd like to have some sort of display on the taskbar showing the ping times to a particular server. Is there a way to set this up? (I'm hoping to avoid writing a whole GUI program just for this. I don't even know that I can.)

Even just being able to show the command line's output on the taskbar would be fine.

Something sort of like this would be perfect:

[image]

I did Google around for a solution. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/661132/show-current-ping-to-website-on-taksbar) which is sort of similar, but **the only answer there has some issues - the suggested app only distinguishes between "successful ping" and "unsuccessful ping", whereas I want to know more precisely *how much* ping I have.**

I found zero results for displaying command line output on the taskbar.

Comment: Have you done any research? If so, share what you have done so far. If not, you may want to a look at ***[ask]***, then update your question.

Comment: This is the same question as the one you linked. If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question please consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it instead of repeating the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method, which still requires a little bit of programming, would be to create a simple webpage that uses a javascript function to make an ajax get request to the site you want.  You capture the time_before, and then time_after on the success event of the ajax.  Use the time difference to update the webpage Title... which is used to label the browser tab... which would show up on your Windows task bar automatically.  Maybe this sounds complex but shouldn't be bad to create.

Another question has some similar ajax/javascript info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: Clever solution! But I use icons only on my taskbar. Nice try, though. :D

Comment: Same logic could be used to change the favicon, maybe just used red/yellow/green icons, or create a scale 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 etc. icons.  Otherwise developing a tray icon program sounds like what you want.